# How to break on localStorage changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for a way to break on any localStorage changes. I have found that there are some mysterious entries that I have no idea where that is coming from and I would like the debugger to break on any changes so that I can inspect the code. This includes:

```
localStorage.someKey = someValue;
localStorage["someKey"] = someValue;
localStorage.setItem("someKey", someValue);
```

Since there are so many ways to alter/create an entry in localStorage, simply overriding `.setItem` and do `debugger;` will not work. Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: @PatrickEvans `StorageEvent`s will not be emitted on the same page. It's only for different pages that are on the same domain.

Comment: I would create an iframe or another tab with the same URL and a listener for `storage` event. It wouldn't stop the original code in the debugger but still could be helpful.

Comment: A crazy idea: since devtools detects these changes (in Chrome) you can set a breakpoint inside it: undock devtools into a window, press CtrlShift-i to open devtools-for-devtools, find the code that detects DOM storage changes, set a breakpoint.

Comment: @wOxxOm That will probably not have the call stack that I wanted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not on the native `localStorage` object, but on a proxied version:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  value: new Proxy(localStorage, {
    set: function (ls, prop, value) {
      console.log(`direct assignment: ${prop} = ${value}`);
      debugger;
      ls[prop] = value;
      return true;
    },
    get: function(ls, prop) {
      // The only property access we care about is setItem. We pass
      // anything else back without complaint. But using the proxy
      // fouls 'this', setting it to this {set: fn(), get: fn()}
      // object.
      if (prop !== 'setItem') {
        if (typeof ls[prop] === 'function') {
          return ls[prop].bind(ls);
        } else {
          return ls[prop];
        }
      }
      // If you don't care about the key and value set, you can
      // drop a debugger statement here and just
      // "return ls[prop].bind(ls);"
      // Otherwise, return a custom function that does the logging
      // before calling setItem:
      return (...args) => {
        console.log(`setItem(${args.join()}) called`);
        debugger;
        ls.setItem.apply(ls, args);
      };
    }
  })
});
```

We create a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for `window.localStorage` that will intercept [property assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set) (handling the `localStorage.someKey = someValue` and `localStorage["someKey"] = someValue` cases) and [property access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get) (handling the `localStorage.setItem("someKey", someValue)` case).

Now we need to point `window.localStorage` at our proxy, but it's read-only. However, it's still configurable! We can redefine its value with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Is there a way we can access the key and value set in the Proxy#get part? I would like to log it systematically.

Comment: @rriemann Yes, by returning a custom function when `setItem` is called. See edit.

Comment: Not worked for me. Applied this code on page, when I change localStorage, it works. But where is some tricky timer on page, which I try to figure out. This timer sets value in localStorage, and when it happens, no logs appear. Is there any other options to update localStorage, which this tricky code can use?