# LocalStorage variable constantly switching between two values by itself and without a reason—is this a Chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage

I'm a website owner, and the buttons that control the light/dark modes on my site are just simple divs that use LocalStorage in a very simple way to update the style of the page according to the user's choice:

```
<div id="go-to-dark-mode-icon" onclick="localStorage.setItem('brightness', 'dark'); location.reload()">
   &nbsp;
</div>
<div id="go-to-light-mode-icon" onclick="localStorage.setItem('brightness', 'white'); location.reload()">
   &nbsp;
</div>
```

But lately I've been having a weird bug that only seem to happen on my computer's Google Chrome (not on mobile, on Edge, or on my friends' computers as far as I know): there are times when the divs work just fine, and then all of a sudden I click on one of them and nothing changes. And from that moment on, everything goes crazy—I refresh the page and sometimes it's dark and other times it's not, sometimes certain elements are displayed in their light mode version while others are in their dark mode version, etc.

And whenever this craziness ensues, if I open Chrome's developer tools and go to the LocalStorage tab, **I can see the "brightness" variable constantly swicthing back and forth between "dark" and "white"** every one or two seconds, but it does so by itself, unprovoked, even after the page is loaded and without clicking on anything.

This behaviour is so weird that I can't possibly imagine there's a bug with the rest of my code, not only because it has nothing to do with how light and dark modes are handled but also because this is probably impossible to achieve with simply JavaScript even if I wanted to. So what's going on? Is this a known Chrome bug? Is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092423/how-to-break-on-localstorage-changes for how you can make a breakpoint when local storage changes. Then you should be able to see what's causing it.

Comment: "or on my friends' computers"
There was a Chrome update very recently. Is it possible that you and your friends are using different versions of Chrome?